# Concatenate strings in a column with grouping

Tags: r

I have a data frame as shown below, i need to concatenate the strings in issue column by grouping ID,Location and Customer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWION.png)
ID Location Customer Issue
1   x        a       Issue1
2   y        b       Issue2
3   z        c       Issue3
1   x        a       Issue4
2   y        b       Issue5
2   y        b       Issue6

my result should look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdDcO.png)

ID Location Customer Issues
1  x         a       Issue1, Issue4
2  y         b       Issue2, Issue5, Issue6
3  z         c       Issue3

Can anyone help with the r code for this?

Also i need to list the unique issues if issues are repeating the grouping

Comment: `aggregate(Issue~ID + Location + Customer, df, toString)`

Comment: Thank you. solution is working fine.

Comment: Is it possible to list the unique issues if issues are repeating in the same grouping.

Comment: `aggregate(Issue~ID + Location + Customer, df, function(x) toString(unique(x)))`

Comment: If i want to add one more column for concatenation along with Issue column. suppose other column name is "issue_code", for each issue i will have one issue code. how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Id, Location, Customer) %>%
  mutate(Issue = paste0(Issue, collapse = ",")) %>%
  distinct()
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   ID, Location, Customer [3]
#      ID Location Customer Issue           
#      <dbl> <fct>    <fct>   <chr>               
#1     1 x        a       Issue1,Issue4       
#2     2 y        b       Issue2,Issue5,Issue6
#3     3 z        c       Issue3
```